# How usual is seeing or picturing a space lidar from Earth?

Tags: cnsa

Recently, photographs taken on Earth of the 532 nm beam emitted by the [Aerosol and Carbon Detection Lidar](https://space.oscar.wmo.int/instruments/view/acdl) have [hit the news](https://www.vice.com/en/article/bvm9y5/green-lasers-sky-hawaii-chinese-satellite), perhaps also because of the nice pictures and because *Chinese space laser shooting at the US* makes for nice clickbait (it's even true), even if it's not really news and not particularly relevant.  ACDL is far from the first space-borne lidar operating at 532 nm; for example, [CALIOP](https://space.oscar.wmo.int/instruments/view/caliop) has been doing so since 2006, and several newer lidars exist.  That makes me think it should be relatively routine for Earth-based observers to see space-based lidars, even if it probably takes a pretty sensitive camera and a dark sky to see one.

[image: Image of ACDL probing the Earth near Hawaii]
*Source: National Astronomical Observatory of Japan (NAOJ)*

Is it common for space-based lidars to be seen or pictured from Earth, or is this rather unusual?  Why would it be unusual?